# implement the function lines in haskell

Tags: haskell

e.g. `lines "One string\non\neach line"` = `["One string","on","each line"]`

Use pattern matching and recursion on lists, the list constructors, but no other functions.

That's my solution, I think logically, but it still gives me an error`

```
lines :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
lines [] = [[]]
lines (x:'\n':xs) = [x] : lines xs
lines (x:xs) = x : lines xs
```

Comment: This looks like homework.  What have you tried and we'll help with any problems you've encountered, but you shouldn't ask someone to do your homework for you on SO.

Comment: oh sorry , I forgot to put on my solution

Comment: In `lines (x:xs) = x : lines xs`, `x` has type `Char`, so `x :` has type `[Char] -> [Char]`. Obviously this cannot be correct because the output type must be `[[Char]]`. Note that you only want to prepend `x` to the *first element* of the list `lines xs`.

Comment: I would suggest you try to break the problem down a bit, and work one step at a time. Start by thinking about how you'd extract just the *first* line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need a way of retrieving all the text before the first newline character. This is simple recursion:

```
beforeNewLine :: [Char] -> [Char]
beforeNewLine ""        = ""
beforeNewLine ('\n':xs) = ""
beforeNewLine (x:xs)    = x : beforeNewLine xs
```

Likewise, we need to be able to get all the text after the first newline character:

```
afterNewLine :: [Char] -> [Char]
afterNewLine ""        = ""
afterNewLine ('\n':xs) = xs
afterNewLine (x:xs)    = afterNewLine xs
```

Put it all together:

```
myLines :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
myLines "" = []
myLines xs = (beforeNewLine xs) : myLines (afterNewLine xs)
```

Comment: By the way, what's the difference between "" and [] , cause String == [Char]. In my opinion, "" is an empty list of Char, so are they the same?

Comment: They represent the same value, but `""` tells the type checker that it must be a list of characters, whereas `[]` only tells the type checker that it is a list, and lets the type checker on infer what type of list it is. So `"" :: [a]` is only valid for `a == Char`, but `[] :: [a]` is valid for any `a`.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you had already knew the result of `lines` for all but the first character of your input. How would you add the first character onto that result?

```
charon :: Char -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
charon '\n'     css  = [] : css    -- to begin with newline, insert blank line
charon c         []  = [[c]]       -- very last char is in line of its own
charon c (cs : css)  = (c : cs) : css  -- else put char in first line
```

And with that mystery solved,

```
lines = foldr charon []
```

For years, I have made students bang their fists on the furniture and chant "*what* do you *do* with the *emp*ty *list*? *what* do you *do* with *x* cons *xs*?". Sometimes it helps.

Comment: "what do you do with the empty list? what do you do with x cons xs?" Exactly! Probably the most important line in the answer, and a thousand other answers.

Comment: Ok, but what does this have to do with ferrying souls across the river Styx?